# How to return one single row from groupped by columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like this

```
ID Specified TIN
-----------------
1       0   tin1   
2       0   tin1  
3       1   tin1    
4       0   tin2  
5       0   tin3   
6       1   tin3 
7       1   tin3
```

I need to count rows groupped by TIN, Specified columns - but result should one row for each TIN:

```
TIN   ZEROSpecified   NOTZEROSpecified
tin1       2                 1
tin2       0                 1
tin3       1                 2
```

Important notice - i have only 2 values for Specified column -  0 and 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TIN, 
SUM(case when Specified=0 then 1 else 0 end) as ZeroSpecified,
SUM(case when Specified<>0 then 1 else 0 end) as NOTZEROSpecified
FROM table
GROUP BY TIN
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! i forgot about sum function)

Comment: You need to edit the second case, this isn't correct; 'Specified<>1'

Answer (score 1):

Pretty Simple;

```
SELECT
TIN
,SUM(CASE WHEN Specified = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ZEROSpecified
,SUM(CASE WHEN Specified <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NotZEROSpecified
FROM TableName
GROUP BY TIN
```